# Are there any specifications on what ports are there for back-end application?

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

So yesterday I was creating a DockerFile and I noticed that the port we were exposing was 8080 and I understand that Node Web Apps run on 8080. Why 8080??? Can't we use 3000 or 3001? Is it something with Docker or with Node?

```
const express = require('express');
// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Comment: You can use whatever port you want.

Comment: Normally anything below 1024 is reserved for OS usage, e.g. 80 is the HTTP port while 443 is HTTPS. You can pick any port above 1024 for your needs when you're making an application. 8000 and 8080 are somewhat frequent for running internet applications since they replace port 80. In one case you have 80 plus two zeroes, in the other it's 80 twice. It's easy to remeber. Nothing stops you from choosing 21913 or 49465 or 57822 or anything else, though. However, if you're going to be developing a lot of applications, it's useful to be able to remember which port you've chosen for each.

Comment: I see lots of Dockerfiles for Node applications that use the default Express port 3000.  Generally the `EXPOSE`d port in a Dockerfile will be the default port for whatever framework the service uses.  You can pick any port you want and it's okay to have multiple services choosing the same port internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose any port or set of ports using `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile.

```
EXPOSE 8080 3000 3001
```

Generally, the Node application uses default port as 3000. But you can change it with configurations.